# Complex Integral? Saddle Point Method?

Tags: complex-analysis

$$I(k) = \int_{0}^{∞} \frac{\sin(kx)}{x} dx$$

I have no idea how to evaluate this....  but I'm guessing the method of steepest descents (saddle point method) may work.... but not sure.

Comment: You can use double dollar signs to get displayed equations, which look better especially for things like integrals with limits. By the way, your integral is missing the integration variable.

Comment: Are you talking about $I(k)$ instead of $I(x)$?

Comment: thank you.....  didn't notice that.

Comment: The integration variable is still missing.

Comment: i thought that was there .....  i put it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining

$$\forall\,0<M\in\Bbb R\;\;\;,\;\,\Gamma_M:=\{z\in\Bbb C\;:\;|z|=M\,,\,\Im(z)>0\Longrightarrow z=Me^{it}\,,\,0\leq t\leq\pi\}$$

we define the complex path

$$\Gamma:=[-R,-\epsilon]\cup\Gamma_\epsilon\cup[\epsilon,R]\cup\Gamma_R\,\,\,,\,\,\epsilon,R\in\Bbb R^+\,\,,\,\epsilon<<R$$

Defining now $\,\displaystyle{f(z):=\frac{e^{ikz}}{z}}\,$ and using the corollary to the lemma in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83828/definite-integral-calculation-with-0-pole-and) , we get (all the integrals are evaluated following the positive orientation):

$$Res_{z=0}(f)=\lim_{z\to 0}e^{ikz}=1\Longrightarrow\int_{\Gamma_\epsilon}f(z)\,dz=\pi i$$

And since [Jordan's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan's_lemma) gives us at once $\,\displaystyle{\int_{\Gamma_R}f(z)\,dz\xrightarrow [R\to\infty]{}0}\,$ -- or directly:

$$\left|\int_{\Gamma_R}\frac{e^{ikz}}{z}dz\right|\leq\max_{|z|=R}\frac{e^{-Rk}}{R}\pi R\xrightarrow[R\to\infty]{}0\;\;\text{(as long as}\,k>0)--$$

we get (since $\,f(z)\,$ is holomorphic within $\,\Gamma\,$):

$$0=\oint_\Gamma f(z)\,dz\xrightarrow[R\to\infty]{}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{ikx}}{x}dx-\pi i$$

and taking the imaginary part above we get

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{i\sin kx}{x}dx=\pi i\Longrightarrow \int_0^\infty\frac{\sin kx}{x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

since the integrand is an even function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact that [the sinc function is the Fourier transform of a rectangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25903) and then apply the [Plancherel theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

Very roughly since the actual solution is long to type out:

You can calculate this definite integral by using a method called "contour integration," which informally I think you can describe as line integration for complex variables.

The method behind contour integration is to take a complex-valued function, integrate it along some closed curve, and then extract the real-variable integral you want from that integration. For example, you can say:

$$ I(k) = \Im \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{ikx}}{x} \ dx $$

Now you can evaluate instead $\displaystyle \int_{\gamma} \dfrac{e^{ikz}}{z} \ dz$, where $\gamma$ is the contour that runs from $-R$ to $R$ along the real axis, with a small concave down infinitesimal semi-circle at the origin, and then along the semi-circle from $R$ to $-R$.

Notice that in the limit, along the real-axis you get $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{ikz}}{z} \ dz $. By use of Jordan's lemma (see Wikipedia), you can show that the integral along the semi-circle goes to zero.

Comment: Shouldn't that be the Imaginary part of I(k)?  Also why are the limits of integration changing?

Comment: Ah, yes that should be the imaginary part not the real part. The limits of integration are changed for symmetry sake.