# Fourier transform of the Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis

Is the Fourier transform of the Fourier transform of $f(t)$: $$\hat{\hat{f(t)}} = f(-t)$$ or  $$\hat{\hat{f(t)}} = 2\pi f(-t)$$
?

I have read the two versions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Invertibility_and_periodicity) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241469/fourier-transform-of-fourier-transform) (respectively) for example.

And also, can I show this from the definition ? I tried this :

$$ \hat{\hat{f(t)}} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-i\omega t}dt\right)e^{-i\omega t}dt $$ 
$$= \hat{f(\omega)}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-i\omega t}dt$$

but I don't really know where I'm going with this...

Comment: Both are "correct", it depends on the definition

Comment: You mean it depends on the definition of the Fourier transform ? Which one is correct if I use the following definition : $\hat{f(\omega)} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-i\omega t}dt$

Comment: The $2 \pi$ one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

The proof below might be wrong, due to a faulty substituion, as pointed out by Dan in the comments.

I marked the equation in question with a question mark.

**Original Proof Attempt:**

You reuse the $t$ and $\omega$ variables, also you factor out $\hat{f}(\omega)$ while there is an integration running over it and it is not constant. So your derivation might better start like this:

\begin{align}
\hat{\hat{f}}(\omega)
&= 
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\hat{f}(t)e^{-i\omega t}dt \\
&= 
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}
f(\tau)e^{-it \tau}d\tau \, e^{-i\omega t}dt \\
&= 
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}
f(\tau)e^{-it (\tau+\omega)}d\tau \, dt \\
\end{align}

Switching integration order gives
$$
\begin{align}
\hat{\hat{f}}(\omega)
&=
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}
f(\tau)e^{-it (\tau+\omega)}dt \, d\tau \\
&= 
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}
e^{-it (\tau+\omega)}dt \, f(\tau) \, d\tau \\
&{? \atop =} 
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}
e^{-it u}du \, f(\tau) \, d\tau \\
&= \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \!\!
2\pi\delta(u) \, f(\tau) d\tau \\
&= 2\pi \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \!\!
\delta(\tau + \omega) \, f(\tau) d\tau \\
&= 2\pi \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \!\!
f(\tau) \, \delta(\tau-(-\omega)) \, d\tau \\
&= 
2\pi \, f(-\omega)
\end{align}
$$
where in between a substitution $u = t + \omega$ with $du = dt$ was used.

Comment: See e.g. [Integration by substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution)

Comment: So, where does the formula with $2\pi$ come from ?

Comment: I fixed the mistake.

Comment: Ok. I still don't understand how $e^{-it(\tau+\omega)}dt = e^{-itu}du$ though... if $u = (t+\omega)$  then $e^{-itu}du =  e^{-it^2-it\omega}dt$ ?

Comment: Yes, see the line before I put in $u$.

Comment: How do you prove $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-itu}dt$ is $2\pi\delta(u)$?

Comment: You change $\tau + \omega$ to $u$ when you supposedly make the substitution $u = t + \omega$. As written this proof is not correct.

Comment: Hello Dan, thanks for your comment. Looking at it after all this time I agree it looks fishy. I lack the time to  redo the calculation right now. Need to check back over the weekend. I tried to delete it in the meantime, but I am not allowed to do this for an accepted answer.